# How can I pass an array to a function in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, function

Question 1:

I want to pass an array to a function. But the passed argument is changed in the function. Is it called by value?

Question 2:

```
#my ($name, $num, @array)= @_;   <=1 )
my $name = shift;                <=2 )
my $num = shift;
my @array = shift;
```

Case 1 and 2 has different output. Why did it occur?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @test1;
push @test1, ['a', 1];
push @test1, ['b', 1];
push @test1, ['c', 1];
push @test1, ['d', 1];
push @test1, ['e', 1];

for (my $i=0; $i< scalar(@test1); $i++) {
    print "out1: $test1[$i][0]  $test1[$i][1]\n";
}

test_func("test_func", 10, @test1);

sub test_func {
    #my ($name, $num, @array)= @_;   <=1)
    my $name = shift;                <=2)
    my $num = shift;
    my @array = shift;

    print "$name\n";
    print "$num\n";

    for (my $i=0; $i< scalar(@test1); $i++) {
        print "$array[$i][0]  $array[$i][1]\n";
    }

    for (my $i=0; $i< scalar(@test1); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i][0] eq 'a') {
            $array[$i][0] = 'z';
        }
    }
    for (my $i=0; $i< scalar(@test1); $i++) {
        print "change: $array[$i][0]  $array[$i][1]\n";
    }
}

for (my $i=0; $i< scalar(@test1); $i++) {
    print "out2: $test1[$i][0]  $test1[$i][1]\n";
}
```

#

Below is the test output.

```
out1: a  1
out1: b  1
out1: c  1
out1: d  1
out1: e  1
test_func
10
a  1
b  1
c  1
d  1
e  1
change: z  1
change: b  1
change: c  1
change: d  1
change: e  1
out2: z  1 <= Why did it change?
out2: b  1
out2: c  1
out2: d  1
out2: e  1
```

Answer (score 11):

> I want to pass an array to a function [...] has different output. Why did it occur?

You cannot pass an array to a <strike>function</strike> sub. Subs can only take a list of scalars as arguments.

```
test_func("test_func", 10, @test1);
```

is the same as

```
test_func("test_func", 10, $test1[0], $test1[1], $test1[2], $test1[3], $test1[4]);
```

You are creating a new array in `test_func` when you do

```
my ($name, $num, @array) = @_;
```

`shift` returns the first element of `@_`, which is necessarily a scalar. `@_` is an array, and elements of arrays are scalars. The equivalent would be

```
my $name  = shift(@_);
my $num   = shift(@_);
my @array = splice(@_);
```

To pass an array to a sub, one would normally pass a reference to it.

```
test_func("test_func", 10, \@test1);

my ($name, $num, $array) = @_;

my $name  = shift;
my $num   = shift;
my $array = shift;

say "@$array";
```

---

> But the passed argument is changed in the function. Is it called by value?

Perl never passes by value. It always passes by reference. If you change any element of `@_`, it will change the corresponding argument in the caller.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { $_[0] = "def"; }  my $x = "abc"; f($x); say $x;'
def
```

But that's not the issue. You don't change any elements of `@_`. What you are doing is changing the single array referenced by both `$test[0]` and `$array[0]`.

This is what you are doing:

```
my $ref1 = [ 'a', 1 ];  # aka $test1[0]
my $ref2 = $ref1;       # aka $array[0]
$ref2->[0] = 'z';       # Changes the single array (not $ref1 or $ref2).
```

It's short for

```
my @anon = ( 'a', 1 );
my $ref1 = \@anon;      # aka $test1[0]
my $ref2 = $ref1;       # aka $array[0]
$ref2->[0] = 'z';       # Changes @anon (not $ref1 or $ref2).
```

[Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable)'s `dclone` can be used to make a "deep copy" of an array.

```
my $ref1 = [ 'a', 1 ];
my $ref2 = dclone($ref1);  # clones the reference, the array, 'a' and 1.
$ref1->[0] = 'y';          # Changes the original array
$ref2->[0] = 'z';          # Changes the new array
```